# difference between sizeof *ptr and sizeof **ptr when allocating memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof, dereference, pointer-to-member

In this piece of code:

```
void func(size_t dim, double **ptr){
   (*ptr) = malloc(dim * sizeof **ptr);
   /* Perform Calculations...*/
}
```

What is the difference between using `sizeof **ptr` and `sizeof *ptr`? This is confusing me. It seems to have no difference when I'm dealing with `int*` and `double*` types, but when I'm dealing with `chars*`, using `sizeof **ptr` results in a segmentation fault. Could you help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The segmentation violation is going to be caused by the code that you have not shown.

Comment: Allocating memory for what? Doing what kind of calculations? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between using `sizeof **ptr` and `sizeof *ptr`?

`sizeof *ptr` is the size of the type that `ptr` points to.

`sizeof **ptr` is the size of the type that is pointed to by what `ptr` points to.

The declaration `double **ptr` says `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to a `double`. Then `*ptr` is a pointer to a `double`, so `sizeof *ptr` is the size of a pointer to `double`. And `**ptr` is a `double`, so `sizeof **ptr` is the size of a `double`.

> It seems to have no difference when I'm dealing with `int*` and `double*` types, but when I'm dealing with `chars*`, using `sizeof **ptr` results in a segmentation fault.

If a pointer is four bytes in your system, an `int` is four bytes, and a `double` is eight bytes, then allocating enough space for an `int` or `double` also allocates enough space for a pointer. However, allocating space for a `char` is not enough for a pointer.

This is actually unlikely to make a noticeable different for a single pointer, as `malloc` commonly works in units of eight or 16 bytes, so asking it to allocate space for a `char` would actually give enough for a pointer, notwithstanding compiler optimization. However, if you allocate `dim * sizeof **ptr` bytes where `ptr` has type `char **` and `dim` is large, then this will only allocate enough space for `dim` `char` elements and not enough space for `dim` pointers.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: If I want to perform operations with the `double` value that `**ptr` is pointing to and update the value of `ptr` outside the function, I should declare as `(*ptr) = malloc(dim * sizeof **ptr)`, right?

Comment: @Lgcos: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers inside the sizeof() operator aren't evaluated, let's say you have this:

```c
int * pointer = malloc(sizeof(* pointer));
```

What you're doing here is "malloc sizeof pointed type", advantage is you can change the type of the pointer without changing the sizeof() part.

Now, with a double pointer:

```c
int ** pointer;

// allocate enough space to store a pointer: sizeof(* pointer) <--> sizeof(int *) 
pointer = malloc(sizeof(* pointer));
```

And with this:

```c
int ** pointer;
// allocate enough space to store an int: sizeof(** pointer) <--> sizeof(int) 
pointer = malloc(sizeof(** pointer));
```

On a 64 bits system, first case would likely give you 8 bytes, and second case only 4 bytes, potentally crashing if you meant to use 8 bytes.

```c
(*ptr) = malloc(dim * sizeof **ptr);
```

You're storing inside *ptr, which is of type double*, since ptr has type double**.
You allocate n*sizeof(double) bytes, not n*sizeof(double*) bytes, might be different on your system.

Or maybe the crash happens when you access that memory.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `ptr` is declared like

```
double **ptr
```

That is the original pointer used as an argument is passed to the function by reference indirectly through a pointer to it.

Within the function you need to assign a value to the original pointer by means of dereferencing the parameter.

```
(*ptr) = malloc(dim * sizeof **ptr);
```

The original pointer `*ptr` must be assigned with the address of a dynamically allocated array of doubles. So dereferencing the pointer in the expression

```
sizeof **ptr
```

you will get the size of an object of the type `double`.

To make it more clear you could use for example an intermediate pointer like

```
double *tmp = malloc(dim * sizeof *tmp );
*ptr = tmp;
```

As for the type of the operand in the expression `sizeof *ptr` then it has the type `double *` and it produces the size of an object of the pointer type `double *` instead of the required size of an object of the type `double`.